# The periods of the Weierstrass function $\wp(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, periodic-functions, elliptic-functions

Is it true that the periods $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ of $\wp(z)$ are $\omega_1 = 4K$ and $\omega_2 = 4iK'$, respectively? Here, $K = K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, and $K' = K(k')$ with $k' = \sqrt{1 - k^2}$, where $0 < k < 1$ is the elliptic modulus. I could not find these stated explicitly anywhere, but I deduced that $\omega_1 = 4K$ and $\omega_2 = 4iK'$ from some relations in Greenhill's book on elliptic functions. It seems to be correct, but it bothers me that I could not find a single book on elliptic functions (not even Whittaker and Watson) that states that $\omega_1 = 4K$ and $\omega_2 = 4iK'$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true unless I misunderstand your question. The periods $\omega_1,\omega_2$   form a pair of generic complex numbers, which cannot be parameterized with a single elliptic modulus $k$. Note in particular that simultaneous rescaling $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto (\lambda\omega_1,\lambda\omega_2)$ does not change $k$.

Geometrically, $\wp(z)$ describes uniformization of elliptic curve realized as a two-sheeted covering of $\mathbb P^1$. The modulus $k$ is related to the anharmonic ratio of the branch points $e_1,e_2,e_3,\infty$, which remains invariant under rescalings.

For explicit relation between $e$'s and $\omega$'s, see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassHalfPeriods/27/02/01/).

Comment: But one can actually express $e_1$, $e_3$ in terms of $k$. See Greenhill p. 57.

Comment: @glebovg No, one can't. $k$ determines $J$ but not $\Delta$. One can however rescale the periods so that $\Delta$ is given by the formula (100) in your book (observe "we may put" just before) and then indeed $e$'s are expressed in terms of $k$ as well.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense.

Comment: By the way, Greenhill denotes the modulus by $\kappa$ and its square by $k$.

Comment: By "rescaling" do you mean something like Klein's normalization of the periods: $\Omega_1 = \omega_1 \Delta^{1/12}$, $\Omega_2 = \omega_2 \Delta^{1/12}$? Will this work?

Comment: @glebovg Yes, something of this type. To be honest I didn't know that there is a normalization which has a name.

Comment: I do not think this normalization is well-known. It appears to have been first introduced by [Klein](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02297507). Greenhill's book is the only book that I know of that mentions it. Klein and Fricke (Vorlesungen uber die Theorie der elliptischen Modulfunctionen, 1890) also consider other normalizations such as $\Omega_1 = \omega_1 \sqrt{g_3/g_2}$, $\Omega_2 = \omega_2 \sqrt{g_3/g_2}$.