# Quantities $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, elliptic-curves, convention, elliptic-functions

This question is somewhat related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924322/the-periods-of-the-weierstrass-function-wpz). Let $\lambda$ be the modular lambda function. Greenhill (Elliptic Functions, p. 57) states that we may put
$$g_2 = \frac{1 - \lambda + \lambda^2}{12}, \quad g_3 = \frac{(1 + \lambda)(1 - 2\lambda)(2 - \lambda)}{432}, \quad \Delta = \frac{\lambda^2 (1 - \lambda)^2}{256}, \tag{$\ast$}$$
where $g_2$, $g_3$ are the invariants, and $\Delta$ is the discriminant, of the Weierstrass cubic $4x^3 - g_2 x - g_3$. I believe this convention is due to Klein. However, my question is why would one adopt such a convention and can one truly treat them as equalities?

In general, if $X = ax^4 + 4bx^3 + 6cx^2 + 4dx + e$ then we define $\Delta(X) = g_2^3 - 27g_3^2$, where
$$g_2(X) = ae - 4bd + 3c^2 \quad \text{and} \quad g_3(X) = ace + 2bcd - ad^2 - b^2 e - c^3.$$

Also, I find it intriguing that the quantities $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$ associated with the Legendre cubic $x(x - 1)(x - \lambda)$ are precisely $(\ast)$. I know that the two elliptic curves
$$E_1 : y^2 = 4x^3 - g_2 x - g_3 \quad \text{and} \quad E_2 : y^2 = x(x - 1)(x - \lambda)$$
are isomorphic (because their $j$-invariant is the same), but is there something deeper going on here?

Comment: Could you please explain what you find intriguing? Your general definition with $X=ax^4 + 4bx^3 + 6cx^2 + 4dx + e$ specializes to the first set of formulas when $X=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$. Surely that's not surprising. What do you mean by the quantities being 'precisely the ones above'?

Comment: @Prometheus No, that is not surprising. Greenhill claims that we may use $(\ast)$ to define $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$. But then $g_2 = g_2(E_2)$, $g_3 = g_3(E_2)$, $\Delta = \Delta(E_3)$, which I think is peculiar.

Comment: I shouldn't believe that it's peculiar. $y^2 = x(x - 1)(x-\lambda)$ is a standard normal form for elliptic curves. [look up "legendre normal form"]

Comment: @BalarkaSen Yes, I know. I think the "modern" formulation of Greenhill's line of thought is the following: Put the Weierstrass elliptic curve $E_1$ into the Legendre form $E_2$, calculate $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$, which are $(\ast)$, and then simply use $(\ast)$ to define $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, I do believe that is the construction, @glebovg.

Comment: If $g_2$ and $g_3$ as defined in $(*)$ *didn't* match $g_2(E)$ and $g_3(E)$, then there would be something seriously wrong. Otherwise it's just two expressions for the same quantity. I don't find $g_2=g_2$ and $g_3=g_3$ peculiar at all. These identities are trivial.

Comment: @Prometheus You do not understand. The quantities $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$ cannot technically be defined by $(\ast)$. The elliptic modulus $k$ determines the $j$-invariant, but not $\Delta$. The only quantity that is the same is the $j$-invariant because $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isomorphic. Also, $x$ and $y$ in $E_1$ and $E_2$ are different, we are just using the same symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider $g_2, g_3, \Delta, \lambda$ as functions of the period ratio
$\tau$, then you have to add certain factors to get true equalities.
This is obvious from the fact that the modular forms $g_2, g_3, \Delta$
have nonzero weight: Those functions get multiplied with
powers of $\tau$ when replacing $\tau$ with $-\tau^{-1}$.
On the other hand, $\lambda$ just changes to $1-\lambda$,
thus the right-hand sides of (*) have weight zero.

The factor in question is a suitable power of a weight-1 modular form.
To derive it, use the known formulae
$$\begin{align}
 g_2 &= 60 \operatorname{G}_4
& g_3 &= 140 \operatorname{G}_6
\\ \operatorname{G}_4 &= 2\zeta(4)\operatorname{E}_4
 = \frac{\pi^4}{45}\operatorname{E}_4
& \operatorname{G}_6 &= 2\zeta(6)\operatorname{E}_6
 = \frac{2\pi^6}{945}\operatorname{E}_6
\\ \operatorname{E}_4 &= \frac{1}{2}
 \left(\varTheta_{00}^8 + \varTheta_{01}^8 + \varTheta_{10}^8\right)
& \operatorname{E}_6 &= \frac{1}{2}
 (\varTheta_{00}^4 + \varTheta_{01}^4)
 (\varTheta_{00}^4 + \varTheta_{10}^4)
 (\varTheta_{01}^4 - \varTheta_{10}^4)
\\ \lambda &= \frac{\varTheta_{10}^4}{\varTheta_{00}^4}
& 1 - \lambda &= \frac{\varTheta_{01}^4}{\varTheta_{00}^4}
\\ \Delta &= g_2^3 - 27 g_3^2 = (2\pi)^{12} \operatorname{D}
& \operatorname{D} &=
 \frac{\operatorname{E}_4^3-\operatorname{E}_6^2}{1728}
 = \frac{1}{256}\varTheta_{00}^8 \varTheta_{01}^8 \varTheta_{10}^8
\end{align}$$
where $\varTheta_{00}, \varTheta_{01}, \varTheta_{10}$ are
Jacobi Thetanull functions (of $\tau$, as everything else here),
and $\operatorname{G}_k$ and $\operatorname{E}_k$ are
Eisenstein series of weight $k$, with $\operatorname{E}_k$ normalized
to yield $\lim_{\Im\tau\to\infty}\operatorname{E}_k(\tau) = 1$.

Eliminate $\varTheta_{01}, \varTheta_{10}$ in favor of $\varTheta_{00}$
and $\lambda$. Then you will arrive at
$$\begin{align}
 g_2 &= f^4 \frac{1 - \lambda + \lambda^2}{12}
\\ g_3 &= f^6 \frac{(2-\lambda)(1+\lambda)(1-2\lambda)}{432}
\\ \Delta &= f^{12} \frac{(1 - \lambda)^2 \lambda^2}{256}
\\\text{with}\quad f &= 2\pi\varTheta_{00}^2
\end{align}$$

That said, in elliptic curve equations,
those powers of $f$ can be transformed away,
which is why Greenhill can do what you have described.

**Addendum.**
Suppose instead you use the homogenized 2-parameter lattice form
for $g_2, g_3, \operatorname{G}_4, \operatorname{G}_6, \Delta$, e.g.
$$\operatorname{G}_k(\omega_1,\omega_2) =
\omega_2^{-k}\operatorname{G}_k(\tau,1)
\quad\text{with}\quad \tau = \frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$$

Set $\omega_2 = f(\tau)$ and adjust $\omega_1 = \tau\omega_2$ accordingly.
Then the above-mentioned result can be rewritten as
$$\begin{align}
 g_2(\omega_1,\omega_2) &= \frac{1 - \lambda + \lambda^2}{12}
\\ g_3(\omega_1,\omega_2) &= \frac{(2-\lambda)(1+\lambda)(1-2\lambda)}{432}
\\ \Delta(\omega_1,\omega_2) &= \frac{(1 - \lambda)^2 \lambda^2}{256}
\\\text{with}\quad \omega_2 &= 2\pi\varTheta_{00}^2
\end{align}$$
which is what Greenhill states.
Note however that this requires a specifically normalized lattice;
the normalization is not to $\omega_2=1$ but to $\omega_2=f(\tau)$.

Indeed, for $\tau$ in a certain subset of $\mathbb{H}$,
we can identify
$$f = 4K(\sqrt{\lambda})$$
where $K$ is a complete elliptic integral.
This yields one of the canonical periods used for Jacobian elliptic functions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I truly appreciate your time and effort. Regarding the Addendum, I discussed something similar with O.L. (see the [comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924322/the-periods-of-the-weierstrass-function-wpz/927414#927414)). If we normalize the periods a la Klein: $\Omega_1 = \omega_1 \Delta^{1/12}$, $\Omega_2 = \omega_2 \Delta^{1/12}$, then one can show that $g_2$, $g_3$, $\Delta$ all reduce to $(\ast)$. This is discussed in Greenhill (p. 271).

Comment: I have removed the misunderstandable parts of the addendum and clarified the rest (I hope). Sure about the $\Delta^{1/12}(\omega_1,\omega_2)$? From that I get $\Omega_2 = 2\pi\eta^2$ instead of $\Omega_2 = 2\pi\varTheta_{00}^2 = 2\pi\eta^2\mathfrak{f}^4$ where $\mathfrak{f}$ is a Weber function.

Comment: I am pretty sure. If $\Omega_1 = \omega_1 \Delta^{1/12}$, $\Omega_2 = \omega_2 \Delta^{1/12}$, then $\omega_1 = 4K$, $\omega_2 = 4iK$, which corresponds with your results. By the way, I am using a different convention: $\omega_1$ is the real period and $\omega_2$ is the imaginary period, i.e., $\tau = \omega_2/\omega_1$.

Comment: I have taken a look at Greenhill now.
On p. 270, he implies that normalizing with $\Delta^{1/12}$
turns $g_2$ to $\gamma_2$ and $g_3$ to $\gamma_3$.
In his notation, this is correct.
Nowadays, we write $\gamma_2/12$ and $\gamma_3/216$ for that,
as we relate to $j = 1728J$ instead of $J$
and absorb the occasional factor 27 into $\gamma_3^2$
so that we have $j=\gamma_2^3$, $j-1728=\gamma_3^2$.

Comment: Cf. Wolfram's formulae (7) ... (17) for the [modular
Weber functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeberFunctions.html).
Note that in our notation,
$$\begin{align}
\varTheta_{00} &= \mathfrak{f}^2\eta
&\varTheta_{01} &= \mathfrak{f}_1^2\eta
&\varTheta_{10} &= \mathfrak{f}_2^2\eta
\\ E_4 &= \gamma_2\eta^8
& E_6 &= \gamma_3\eta^{12}
& \operatorname{D} &= \eta^{24}
\end{align}$$
where $\eta$ is the [Dedekind eta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html).

Comment: From this you can deduce
$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{f}^8 &= \mathfrak{f}_1^8 + \mathfrak{f}_2^8
& \mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{f}_1\mathfrak{f}_2 &= \sqrt{2}
\\ \lambda &= \mathfrak{f}_2^8\mathfrak{f}^{-8}
& 1-\lambda &= \mathfrak{f}_1^8\mathfrak{f}^{-8}
\\ 1-\lambda+\lambda^2 &= \mathfrak{f}^{-16} \gamma_2
& (2-\lambda)(1+\lambda)(1-2\lambda) &= 2 \mathfrak{f}^{-24} \gamma_3
\\ (1-\lambda^2)\lambda^2 &= 256 \mathfrak{f}^{-48}
\end{align}$$
The extra powers of $\mathfrak{f}$ are consistent with the findings
in my "Sure about...?" comment.

Comment: What Greenhill means on p. 271 is that we can take $g_2$, $g_3$ and $\Delta$
as in $(*)$ (thus assuming the base period to be $2\pi\varTheta_{00}^2$)
and *then* apply Klein's normalization.
Greenhill explicitly applies (*) to get an expression for $\Delta^{1/12}$
in order to carry out the normalization.
The expression is $(\kappa\kappa'/4)^{1/3}$ in Greenhill's notation and
amounts to $\mathfrak{f}^{-4}$ in our notation.
This turns the base period into
$2\pi\varTheta_{00}^2\mathfrak{f}^{-4} = 2\pi\eta^2$, as I mentioned, and indeed $g_2$ becomes $\gamma_2/12$, and $g_3$ becomes $\gamma_3/216$.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Typo: In my second comment, read $\omega_2 = 4iK'$.

Comment: While we are at that, the last displayed equation in my previous comment should read $(1-\lambda)^2\lambda^2 = 256\mathfrak{f}^{-48}$.